# Intuition behind definition of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, intuition

Let A and B be two n×n matrices with entries from a field F.B is similar to A if there is an n×n invertible matrix P with entries from F such that B=(P^-1)AP.

First thing is what is the actual meaning of similarity here?I am unable to get any Intuition about it.

Secondly what is the Intuition behind the definition?I mean why was it given like that?What could have motivated the mathematicians to define it in that way?

Comment: Similarity relation is closely related to the basis change. If you have a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then by fixing an ordered basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $V$, we can find a matrix representation $A$ of $T$. Now what will happen to the matrix representation $B$ of $T$ when you use another basis of $V$? It turns out that $A$ and $B$ are similar, and the matrix $P$ is closely related to the change of basis.

Comment: Similar matrices represent the same linear transformation, but using a different basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should imagine that $P^{-1}$ has as columns a desired basis of coordinate vectors. Then $P$ sends this basis to the standard coordinate basis, where $A$ does its thing, after which $P^{-1}$ rewrites the result back in the nonstandard coordinates.

In particular, this shows that two similar matrices do “the same thing”, just in different coordinates. For a simple example, similar matrices must have the same dimension of their kernels.